# How should I handle the quota for socket listen() method?

Tags: python, websocket

I am currently making a simple game server with python. I know that in order to receive clients' request for TCP connection, the server program needs to initiate a socket and then execute the `listen()` method. The game server will be a concurrent one since it is required to handle a considerable number of players at the same time (each incoming client request as a new thread).

My question is that what integer value should I pass into the `listen()` method? For example, if I write `listen(5)` it means the server will continuously accept 5 incoming requests before rejection to further requests. But the server should be assumed to accommodate many users (can be several hundred or thousand). I have got a bit confused here. Really appreciate the kind help from you guys.

Comment: A server using `.listen(5)` could easily accommodate thousands of users - as long as you are accepting incoming connections promptly.  The parameter isn't a limit on active connections, it's a limit on unaccepted connections.

Comment: @jasonharper Great clarification! So I have been misunderstanding the nature of listen() method. Thanks a lot for your help again!